# Get and Set specific bits of a value

Tags: python, python-3.9

For a given value, I need to be able to read and write to specific bits of said value.

**Example** :

```py
n = 341
# bin(341) is '0b101010101'

get_bits(n, start = 2, end = 6)
# Returns 10 = '0b1010'

n = set_bits(n, start = 2, end = 6, newValue = 6)
# Replaces bits [2:6] of n with 0b0110
# Makes n = 309 = '0b100110101'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally bits are numbered from right to left.  If you used that standard convention and a start-stop value (like a range), your functions would be simpler to implement with bitwise operators:

```
def get_bits(n, start, end):
    return (n&((1<<end)-1))>>start

def set_bits(n, start, end, value):
    mask = (1<<end) - (1<<start) 
    return (n&~mask) | (value<<start)&mask
```

output:

```
n = 341  # 101010101
         # 876543210 bit numbers

                           # 101010101 = 341 
f"{get_bits(n,3,7):b}"     # ..1010... = 10
                           # 876543210

                           # 101010101 = 341 
f"{set_bits(n,3,7,12):b}"  # 101100101 = 357
                           # ..^^^^...
                           # ..1100... = 12
                           # 876543210
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are three functions to do that ! (The first one contains some common code):

```py
def mask_and_shift(start, end, length):
    """Return a mask and shift value to access [<start>:<end>] of <length> bits"""
    shift = length - end
    mask = (1 << end - start) - 1 << shift
    return mask, shift

def get_bits(n, start, end, length : int = None):
    """Read bits [<start>:<end>] of <n> and return them
    <length> forces <n> into that bit length"""
    mask, shift = mask_and_shift(start, end, length = n.bit_length() if length is None else length)
    return (n & mask) >> shift

def set_bits(n, start, end, newValue, length : int = None):
    """Change bits [<start>:<end>] of <n> to <newValue> and return <n>
    <length> forces <n> into that bit length"""
    mask, shift = mask_and_shift(start, end, length = n.bit_length() if length is None else length)
    return (n & ~mask) | (newValue << shift)
```

(Feel free to suggest improvements, the first line of both is pretty janky as is but I prefer this syntax than separating the ternary operator into another line, because then it really looks like it should be tidied up into `mask_and shift` even though that would make  `mask_and_shift` useless on its own)